# Skipping certain files/classes when using asdoc

Tags: actionscript-3

For some reasons, **asdoc** seems to be only good at 'excluding' classes but not 'skipping', which means all the files will always be walked through and examine for errors.

Is there a way to make **asdoc** really 'skip' some certain files? So it can bypass some already known problematic files and still generate the necessary docs gracefully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't found a way of having asdoc *skip* files, but we have got it working by only providing a whitelist of what files we do want parsed. You could easily write a script that would find all the *.as files and compare them to a 'deny' list and pass those all into asdoc.

Newer versions of asdoc support exclude-sources - see [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-16545?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel). More [here](http://www.adobeforums.com/webx/.59b703a1).

Answer (score 1):

There are some enhancements for the asdoc tool only available in Gumbo(Flex 4):
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4

Besidees the options **"-exclude-sources"** mentioned  by RizwanK, there's also **"-lenient"** to ask asdoc generating the output even when it encounters an error in an ASDoc
comment -- When specified, the lenient option causes the tool to omit the incorrect ASDoc comment from the output, but to complete the build.